# Cancel Auto Renew Memberships in Bulk for certain types

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions, auto-renew

Is there a supported way via the UI to cancel the auto-renew and recurring payment profile on all memberships of a particular type? We're phasing some old membership types out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Sounds like a straightforward job for mysql or a tedious job for a person via the web ui.

In theory, if you were using Drupal, you could use views bulk actions in combination with the civicrm entity module to build a tool to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was going to be a DB or views level operation. Would be a "cool" feature to have as an Action when searching for auto renew memberships.

Comment: Of course, I don't know enough about SearchKit, which is where I'd go to do additional research and potentially implement your proposed feature.